# TS1057: An async function or method must have a valid awaitable return type

Tags: javascript, github, typescript, async-await

On March 28th an issue was opened on Github regarding a bug that async arrow functions generate broken code when targeting ES5, which eventually produces the following error msessage:

> TS1057: An async function or method must have a valid awaitable return
>   type

This is the original issue on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7706

On July 21st Microsoft promised to support `async await` when targeting ES5: http://react-etc.net/entry/async-await-support-for-es5-browsers-pushed-to-typescript-2-1

TypeScript 2.1 is now available on Github. I've downloaded it and you can see the version in its package.json:

```
    "name": "typescript",
    "author": "Microsoft Corp.",
    "homepage": "http://typescriptlang.org/",
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
```

However I'm stil getting the same error when I try to use an async arrow function (and I do have TypeScript 2.1):

> TS1057: An async function or method must have a valid awaitable return
>   type

and someone just opened an issue on Github today regarding this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10805

He was answered that this is duplicate and was referred to the old issue from March, a long time before TypeScript 2.1 was developed, and the issue got closed.

Is someone here working with async arrow functions (and targeting ES5) already or knows what's the current status of that?

Here is my code snippet:

```
async (param1) => {
        var var1 = await func1();
    }
```

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: Post this on the TS list, not here.

Comment: This is the right place for my question because perhaps I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Does the error still exist if you omit the `forEach`, and just create the lambda function? `var f = async (param1) => { ... };`

Comment: Editing questions such that they invalidate existing answers is not okay on SO. I've decided to just delete the answer and move on (I have work to do), but be aware of that for next time please.

Comment: I'm confused. Your post said the error message as "TS1057: An async function or method must have a valid awaitable return type*, but then in a comment on a new-delete answer you are now saying it's some other error message?

Comment: @torazaburo what happened before is that he found another bug in my code, not the one I was reffering to. It was like a tip so I voted up to his answer, but it did not answer my question.

Comment: @torazaburo I removed the other bug he had found from my code snippet so other users won't be confused with that anymore

Comment: @Eric yes it does. Just tried it and I get the same error.

Comment: @Eric I just changed my code snippet to make it clearer, thanks for your question

Comment: @T.J. Crowder OK I didn't know, I apologize. I'm still a new user here relatively, won't do it again.

Comment: How is `func1` defined? Perhaps the issue is that that has a non-awaitable return type?

Comment: @Eric func1 is yet to be written, but I don't think it's the problem since I can remove this statement and leave the function body empty as in your example, and I will still get the same error. The compiler marks the keyword "async" in a red line and hovering it pops the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved it!

The problem was in my code.

Since I use TypeScript, I had to specify the return type:

```
async (param1): Promise<void> => {
        var var1 = await func1();
    }
```

Now TypeScipt compiler doesn't complain anymore.